# Javascript document.form.submit() not working

Tags: php, javascript

This is the code

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once("config.php");
session_start();
require_once("checkuser.php");
checkuser();
       if(isset($_GET['associate']))
               {
$_SESSION['form']['code']=$_GET['associate'];

               }
               if(isset($_GET['branch']))
               {
$_SESSION['form']['br_code']=$_GET['branch'];

               }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<script language="JavaScript" src="ajax.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript">
 function open_window1()
 {
     window.open("help_associate_edit.php");
     }
    function open_window2()
 {
     document.form.action="br_code_edit.php";
     document.getElementById('sub').submit();

     }
     function check()
{

        if(document.frm.br_name.value=="")
        {
        alert("Please specify your branch name");
        document.frm.br_name.focus();
        }
        else if(document.frm.br_code.value=="")
        {
        alert("please specify Branch Code");
        document.frm.br_code.focus();
        }
        else if(document.frm.name.value=="")
        {
        alert("please specify your Name");
        document.frm.name.focus();
        }
        else if(document.frm.father_name.value=="")
        {
        alert("please specify your father's name ");
        document.frm.father_name.focus();
        }
        else if(document.frm.dob.value=="")
        {
        alert("Enter Date Of Birth");
        document.frm.dob.focus();
        }
        else if(document.frm.occupation.value=="")
        {
        alert("Enter occupation");
        document.frm.occupation.focus();
        }
        else if(document.frm.r_address.value=="")
        {
        alert("please specify your address ");
        document.frm.r_address.focus();
        }

        else if(document.frm.phone.value=="")
        {
        alert("please specify phone");
        document.frm.phone.focus();
        }

        else if(document.frm.document.value=="")
        {
        alert("please specify document");
        document.frm.document.focus();
        }else if(document.frm.intro_name.value=="")
        {
        alert("please specify introducer name");
        document.frm.intro_name.focus();
        }
        else if(document.frm.intro_code.value=="")
        {
        alert("please specify introducer code");
        document.frm.intro_code.focus();
        }
        else if(document.frm.t_name.value=="")
        {
        alert("please specify Top associate name");
        document.frm.intro_code.focus();
        }else if(document.frm.t_code.value=="")
        {
        alert("please specify top associate code");
        document.frm.t_code.focus();
        }
        else
        {
         document.frm.submit();
        }
}
 function calldel(a)

{

if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))

{

    document.frm.method="post";

    document.frm.action="associate_edit_verify.php?del="+a;

    document.frm.submit();

}

}

</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Tulip Agritech India Limited</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function mmLoadMenus() {
  if (window.mm_menu_1215174111_0) return;
                                    window.mm_menu_1215174111_0 = new Menu("root",178,30,"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",14,"#555152","#FFFFFF","#F3F3F3","#457FBE","left","middle",5,0,1000,-5,7,true,true,true,0,false,false);
  mm_menu_1215174111_0.addMenuItem("Ongoing&nbsp;Projects","location='ongoing_projects.php'");
  mm_menu_1215174111_0.addMenuItem("Future&nbsp;Plans","location='future_plans.html'");
   mm_menu_1215174111_0.hideOnMouseOut=true;
   mm_menu_1215174111_0.bgColor='#CDCDCD';
   mm_menu_1215174111_0.menuBorder=1;
   mm_menu_1215174111_0.menuLiteBgColor='';
   mm_menu_1215174111_0.menuBorderBgColor='#CDCDCD';

mm_menu_1215174111_0.writeMenus();
} // mmLoadMenus()
//-->
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="mm_menu.js"></script>
</head>
<? if(isset($_GET['associate']))
{?>
<body onload="call();">
<? } else
{
    ?>
    <body>
    <? } ?>
<script language="JavaScript1.2">mmLoadMenus();</script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header_left"><img src="images/company_logo.jpg" alt="company_logo" /></div>
    <div id="header_right">
      <div id="login"><a href="#"><img src="images/login.jpg" alt="login" width="85" height="30" border="0" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="images/register_now.jpg" alt="register_now" width="114" height="30" border="0" /></a></div>
      <div id="search_box">
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td><input name="textfield" type="text" class="search_field" value="KeyWords Here..." /></td>
              <td align="right" valign="middle"><input type="image" name="imageField" src="images/go.jpg" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="navigation"><br />
  <div id="nav">
      <div id="nav_content">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
          <li><img src="images/nav_div.jpg" alt="nav_div" /></li>
          <li><a href="about_us.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
          <li><img src="images/nav_div.jpg" alt="nav_div" /></li>
          <li><a href="associate.html">ASSOCIATE</a></li>
          <li><img src="images/nav_div.jpg" alt="nav_div" /></li>
          <li style="cursor:pointer;"><a href="#" name="link3" id="link1" onmouseover="MM_showMenu(window.mm_menu_1215174111_0,0,34,null,'link3')" onmouseout="MM_startTimeout();" >PLAN & PROJECTS</a></li>
          <li><img src="images/nav_div.jpg" alt="nav_div" /></li>
          <li><a href="contact_us.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="social_network"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Tulip-Agritech-India-limited/317573084925856"><img src="images/facebook.jpg" alt="facebook" border="0" /></a> &nbsp;<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/tulip_india"><img src="images/twitter.jpg" alt="twitter" width="28" height="29" border="0" /></a> &nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="images/youtube.jpg" alt="youtube" width="28" height="29" border="0" /></a> &nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="images/space.jpg" alt="space" width="28" height="29" border="0" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="inner_banner_bg">
  <div id="inner_banner"><img src="images/associate_banner.jpg" alt="associate" width="1000" height="108" /></div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; margin-top:22px;">
  <div id="body">
      <div align="right">

<a href="logout.php"><img src="./image/logout.jpg"  style="width:25px"alt="">Logout</a>
</div><div  align="center">
  <p>  
    <table width="662"><th colspan="2">Registration Form (
* indicates the field is required)</th>
</tr>
<form name="form">
<tr>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="173">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="207">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="266"></tr>
<tr>
<td height="74"><div align="left">Associate code
</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="code" id="code" size="32" value="<?=$_SESSION['form']['code']?>"/></td>
<td width=""><input type="button" name="sub" id="sub" value="Edit" size="32" onClick="call();" /><a href="#" onClick="open_window1();"><img src="image/help-icon.jpg" width="30" height="30"></a><a href="associate_home.php"><strong>Back to menu</strong></a></td></tr>


</form></table>
  </p>
  <div id="edit">
</div>
</div></div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer_bg">
  <div id="footer"><br />
      <div class="footer_text" style="float:left;"><a href="index.php">HOME</a>&nbsp;  |&nbsp; <a href="about_us.html">ABOUT US</a>&nbsp;  |&nbsp; <a href="#">ASSOCIATE&nbsp;</a> |  &nbsp;<a href="plan_projects.html">PLAN &amp; PROJECTS</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="contact_us.html">CONTACT US</a>
          <p>CopyRight All Right Reserved <a href="http://www.tulipindia.biz"><span class="green_text1">tulipindia.biz</span></a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="green_text1" style="float:right;"><span class="black_text1">Address:</span> <span class="green_text3">Registered Office </span><br />
          <span class="black_text2">New Town, PO+PS: Diamond Harbour<br />
            PIN: 743331, 24PARGANAS SOUTH, West Bengal</span> </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my question is that the `document.getElementById('sub').submit();` is not working

How to get this form working?

Comment: Posting all of your code isn't very helpful to us. Please try to isolate a small case and post only the relevant code you think is having trouble

Comment: Tell us how it's not working specifically.

Comment: Its giving error Error: document.getElementById("sub").submit is not a function
Source File: http://localhost/Tulip2011/associate_edit.php?associate=admin#
Line: 14

Comment: @benekastah It is clear what (s)he has tried. `document.getElementById('sub').submit();`

Comment: Thank you  veryone it is solved

Comment: @SomdebMukherjee don't say in the comments it is solved, but rather mark the answer that helped you by clicking on the checkmark next to you. Same goed for your other questions

Answer (score 2):

`#sub` is your submit button. You want to submit the form, so:

```
document.getElementById("form1").submit();
```

Also, since is it is part of a form, it should have a 'form' property, so you can do:

```
document.getElementById("sub").form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to submit a button, where you should be trying to submit the form.

Or click the submit button using JS.

So either:

```
document.getElementById('form1').submit();
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById('sub').click();
```

Comment: Pls upvote my question as because from now i am not allowed to ask question anymore pls pls pls

Comment: Not a valid reason. If your question is good I would upvote it...

Answer (score 0):

You submit the form element, not the button element.

Give the form an id - for example "associateform", then change your javascript to read:

```
document.getElementById('associateform').submit();
```

Another method is here:
http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms in the page, cCheck if this is working

document.forms[0].submit();

or

document.forms[1].submit();